# How to install AEXML module in my iOS 10 and Xcode 8 application using carthage?

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, xcode8, carthage

I am trying to add AEXML module (https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) for XML parsing in my iOS 10 application with Xcode 8. However, I am getting this error while building dependencies with the command `carthage update --platform iOS`.

Swift Version: 3.0

Xcode Version: 8

Carthage Version: 0.17.2

**cartfile**

```
github "tadija/AEXML"
```

**Error after running `carthage update --platform iOS` command**

```
gsirn-021308:ApplePaySwag-Final chandeln$ swift -version
Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

gsirn-021308:ApplePaySwag-Final chandeln$ carthage update --platform iOS
*** Fetching AEXML
*** Checking out AEXML at "4.0.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/q7/bltc5kls62n2mzlvwhctctzr0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.3NnOoT.log
*** Building scheme "AEXML iOS" in AEXML.xcodeproj
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/chandeln/Documents/ApplePaySwag-Final/Carthage/Checkouts/AEXML/Tests/AEXMLTests.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
A shell task (/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/chandeln/Documents/ApplePaySwag-Final/Carthage/Checkouts/AEXML/AEXML.xcodeproj -scheme AEXML iOS -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES clean build) failed with exit code 65:
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/chandeln/Documents/ApplePaySwag-Final/Carthage/Checkouts/AEXML/Tests/AEXMLTests.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```